# Regular properties of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, math-history, formal-languages, automata

Could anyone provide me with a list of graph properties that are regular? I do not mean the definition of a regular graph, I mean graph PROPERTIES.

Why am I asking this? Well, while revisiting the whole discussion on the Chomsky hierachy for formal languages, its possible translation into graphs, and the impact on automata, I found reflections from experts regarding the following question:

Wwhich properties of a graph can be recognized by a finite deterministic automaton? Or, in other words, which properties of a graph are regular?

Apparently people claim that the first answer that comes to mind is not many, if any, given that such kind of automaton lacks memory.

So once I have explained the rationale behind my question, I will be glad to hear from you.

Best regards,

Comment: It seems doubtful that the notion of "properties of a graph [which[ can be recognized by a finite deterministic automaton" is capable of a more succinct or insightful characterization.  Do you have in mind papers where this topic is discussed or used?

Comment: Your question is not very explicit regarding how a finite deterministic automaton "recognizes" a graph property. How is this done? Presumably you.... feed the graph into the automaton and out pops "yes" or "no" depending on whether the property holds or does not hold? But that begs the question: how do you feed a graph into an automaton? What might help is if you can give one example of a graph property that is regular, with explicit description of how that property is recognized by a finite deterministic automaton.

Comment: Well, people like Azriel Rosenfeld play a role in this whole stuff, as far as I know.

Comment: Cf. Manfred Nagl, Graph-Grammatiken: Theorie, Implementirung, Anwendung,  Braunschweig, Vieweg, 1979

Answer (score 1):

As Lee Mosher pointed out, your question is not very explicit. Nevertheless, I think that you might be interested in this [article](https://ac.els-cdn.com/030439759190078G/1-s2.0-030439759190078G-main.pdf?_tid=a3fe6084-8b4c-48d7-8511-23195be68d4b&acdnat=1524738277_2ac4e226a5a2cb65c3b8f74424e461cc):

J. Engelfriet, A regular characterization of graph languages definable in monadic second-order logic. Theoret. Comput. Sci. 88 (1991), no. 1, 139--150.

However, the most important result in that direction is [Courcelle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courcelle%27s_theorem) about monadic second order definable graphs.

Comment: Well, since I am nos a mathematician, but a linguist, it is difficult for me to formulate cerain questions beyond certain point of formalization. Thanks for the links. I already know some of Courcelle's contributions, but I am not so sure how it all comes together.